# How to derive values for $i$ raised to negative integers?

Tags: complex-numbers

This [link](http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/Powers_i.htm#A2) states that the values of $i$ raised to the power of negative integers. How can we derive these values from the positive powers?

Comment: Did you actually try computing, e.g. $i^{-1}$ with the *meaning* of a negative exponent?

Comment: Do you know how to simplify a fraction with complex numerator and denominator so that the denominator becomes real?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$i^{-n}=\frac{1}{i^n}=\frac{i^{3n}}{i^{n}i^{3n}}=\frac{i^{3n}}{i^{4n}}=i^{3n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$n\in\mathbb{N}\implies \exists\ k,l\in\mathbb{N}\ \text{ s.t. } i^{-n} = i^{-(4k) + l} = \left(i^{4k}\right)^{-1}\cdot \left(i^l\right) = i^l$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $i$ is an element of order 4 you know that
$$i^4=1$$
Then there are really only 4 cases to look at corresponding to the 4 residue class of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$
As others have said, it shouldn't be too hard to deal with $n$ negative.

A good exercise is to expand
$$(1+i)^m$$

For various values of $m$, you should be able to find a formula for $m$ congruent to $1,2,3,0$ modulo $4$.